# Angular 15 can't set checked property to mat-checkbox it test spec

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-material, karma-jasmine

I'm for some reason unable to set checked prop to my mat-checkbox in test. Have no idea what can be the problem here

html

```
<form class="example-form">
    <mat-checkbox [checked]="localValue" [disabled]="disabled" (click)="sendCheck()"></mat-checkbox>
</form>
```

ts

```
    localValue!: boolean
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.localValue = this.value ? this.value === 'true' : false
    }

    sendCheck() {
        this.localValue = !this.localValue
        this.cellValueChanged.emit(this.localValue)
    }
```

spec.ts

```
function createComponent<T>(componentType: Type<T>, extraDeclarations: any[] = []) {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                imports: [MatCheckboxModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
                declarations: [componentType, ...extraDeclarations],
            }).compileComponents();

            return TestBed.createComponent<T>(componentType);
        }
        let loader: HarnessLoader
        let checkBoxHarness: MatCheckboxHarness
        let checkboxDebugElement: DebugElement
        let checkboxNativeElement: HTMLElement
        let checkboxInstance: MatCheckbox
        let inputElement: HTMLInputElement
        TestBed.resetTestEnvironment()
        TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting())
        let component: BooleanComponent
        let fixture: ComponentFixture<BooleanComponent>
        beforeEach(async () => {
            fixture = createComponent(BooleanComponent, [CellComponent])
            component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance
            loader = TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader(fixture)
            checkBoxHarness = await loader.getHarness(MatCheckboxHarness)
            checkboxDebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(MatCheckbox))!
            checkboxNativeElement = checkboxDebugElement.nativeElement
            checkboxInstance = checkboxDebugElement.componentInstance
            inputElement = <HTMLInputElement>checkboxNativeElement.querySelector('input')
        })
        it('check', fakeAsync(() => {
            expect(checkboxInstance.checked).toBe(false)
            expect(inputElement.checked).toBe(false)
            component.localValue = true
            fixture.detectChanges()
            console.log(component.localValue)
            console.log(checkboxInstance.checked)
            console.log(inputElement.checked)
            expect(checkboxInstance.checked).toBe(true)
            inputElement.click()
            fixture.detectChanges()
            flush()
            console.log(checkboxInstance.checked)
            expect(checkboxInstance.checked).toBe(false)
        }))
```

I've tried to just basically set property, which bounded to checked to true, but it's not changing anything. Also tried using FormControl and ngModel with standalone, but it was even worse.